# Noncommutative Leray - Hirsch theorem in the context of noncommutative principal bundles

Tags: c-star-algebras, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, principal-bundles

In the literature,  are there some researchs on non commutative analogy of Leray-Hirsch theorem in the context of  non commutative Principal bundles?

Comment: I haven't heard of a Leary Hirsch theorem, but there is something called the Leray-Hirsch theorem that talks about bundles.  Is that what you are referencing?

Comment: @RyanBudney  yes. I am sorry for my typos. I revise it. Thank you!

Comment: There are quantum versions of Leray-Hirsch on toric bundles, in the literature. Are you interested in smt like this?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou Thanks for informing me of this version! yes i am interested in this formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me make clear that by no means would i like to pretend any expertise on the topic (in fact i feel i have a limited understanding of AG in general). However, the question reminded me that i recently came across a "quantum" generalization of Leray-Hirsch theorem (while i was actually searching for something quite different).

So, maybe you would be interested to take a look at:

- [Quantum Cohomology under Birational Maps and Transitions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04799v1), arXiv:1705.04799 [math.AG]

and the references therein; especially:

- [Invariance of quantum rings under ordinary flops II: A quantum Leray–Hirsch theorem](http://content.algebraicgeometry.nl/2016-5/2016-5-027.pdf), Algebraic Geometry 3 (5) (2016) 615–653,
- [Invariance of quantum rings under ordinary flops III: A quantum splitting principle](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cjm/2016/0004/0003/CJM-2016-0004-0003-a002.pdf), Cambridge Journal of Mathematics, Volume 4, Number 3, 333–401, 2016

Hope that is of some interest for your purposes.

Comment: thanks very much, very great. I try to  read the links you kindly provided in the answer